# Extracting various elements/values from BigNumber object

Tags: truffle, bignumber

When I execute `const uniswapReserves = await uniswapDaiEth.getReserves();` code snippet and call out `console.log("uniswapReserves: ", uniswapReserves);` it produces the following output:

> truffle(mainnet_fork)> console.log("uniswapReserves: ", uniswapReserves);

Prints:

```js
[
  BigNumber { _hex: '0x062f5665a81c46a329cff9', _isBigNumber: true },
  BigNumber { _hex: '0xfdaa6616aaa87d55ed', _isBigNumber: true },
  1663098075,
  reserve0: BigNumber { _hex: '0x062f5665a81c46a329cff9', _isBigNumber: true },
  reserve1: BigNumber { _hex: '0xfdaa6616aaa87d55ed', _isBigNumber: true },
  blockTimestampLast: 1663098075
]
```

It clearly returns the output reserve values for each of the two passed token addresses.
Question is how can I extract or reference lets say on of the BigNumber values e.g. reserve0?

Thank you very much,
Samuel

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the `toString` representation of the response.

The `getReserves()` smart contract function returns a tuple with 3 values, `reserve0`, `reserve1` and `blockTimestampLast`. Which is represented in an array like:

```js
[
   { _hex: '0x062f5665a81c46a329cff9', _isBigNumber: true },
   { _hex: '0xfdaa6616aaa87d55ed', _isBigNumber: true },
  1663098075,
]
```

The other part that you see in the console is just to let you know the order of each of the values in the array:

```js
[
 // This is the `reserve0` value, the first value in the array
  BigNumber { _hex: '0x062f5665a81c46a329cff9', _isBigNumber: true },
// This is the `reserve1` value, the second value in the array
  BigNumber { _hex: '0xfdaa6616aaa87d55ed', _isBigNumber: true },
 // This is the `blockTimestampLast` value, the third value in the response array
  1663098075,

  // These values are in order, they indicate that the `reserve0` will be in the first position of the array (index 0). `reserve1` in the second place (index 1), and `blockTimestampLast` in the third place (index 2).
  reserve0: BigNumber { _hex: '0x062f5665a81c46a329cff9', _isBigNumber: true },
  reserve1: BigNumber { _hex: '0xfdaa6616aaa87d55ed', _isBigNumber: true },
  blockTimestampLast: 1663098075
]
```

That's just for information.

You need to use your response as follows:

```js
const reserve0 = uniswapReserves[0];
const reserve1 = uniswapReserves[1];
const blockTimestampLast = uniswapReserves[2];

console.log("reserve0: ", reserve0);
console.log("reserve1: ", reserve1);
console.log("blockTimestampLast: ", blockTimestampLast);
```